# How to show month, year using rich:calendar?

Tags: jsp, jsf, calendar, richfaces

I want to show the current month and year using rich:calendar component during page initialization

Comment: you want rich calender rendered when you page loads ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the calendar control expanded displaying current month and year.

If it is what you want then you can add the following script after control rendering

```
#{rich:component('myCalId')}.doExpand();
```

You can use different such component function of richfaces in that fashion defined [here](http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid771749CB761D933D1157DA408DA084C6FE3FE073.aspx).