# month and year view calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I need a "rich calendar control" that shows "year" and "months" only,when I select a month,that raise an event to handle some operations in that. I googled and [date picker here](http://www.aghausman.net/asp/how-to-show-and-select-monthyear-in-calendar-extender.html) ,but I need a calendar not a picker

and also I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613037/how-to-show-month-year-using-richcalendar) but not useful for me.

Comment: Any harm in using `dropdowns` for month and year ?

Comment: yep,i need rich calendar only.i have a popup ,but need the calendar that shows years in header and months in calendar.

Comment: sometimes it's easier to just build your own

Comment: how to do that? suggest me in that way!

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  A calendar, by defintion, only shows the days of a single month.  There is no such thing as a "rich calender" that only shows months, but not days.  That's like saying "I need a hole filled with dirt".

Comment: i'm researching on, "a calendar that show year on header and all months are below that like the normal calendar where all days displayed".follow this link [link](http://www.aghausman.net/asp/how-to-show-and-select-monthyear-in-calendar-extender.html),i need exactly same but not as a picked but as a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with V4Vendetta. 2 dropdowns would suit better here and be easier on the user just like they do when they select their month and year when entering credit card information.

Comment: okey,i found the dropdown,but we don't have any thing that meet the requirement?i.e. month and year view only?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? Is there any reason you can't use 2 dropdown boxes and it needs to be in a single view control. It's possible, it just seems overkill to me.

Comment: my need is exactly a rich calender control that shows year and month to select and based on the selected month and year i need to bind data to a grid.hope you understand!

Comment: You still havent clearly defined that need. 2 dropdown boxes would still be suitable. Why is a control that would get you to select it combined be any more beneficial? It would require far more options to choose from and make it harder for the user to select the required month and date.

Comment: How could we understand? You haven't defined "rich".

Comment: previously i tried with 2 dropdowns,but i want to make user friendly and want to change the view.

Comment: i want to do it experimentally!

Comment: you can understand by this [link](http://www.aghausman.net/asp/how-to-show-and-select-monthyear-in-calendar-extender.html),i need exactly the same but as a calendar not a picker.

Comment: ok if its just an experiment. So what is the specific trouble you are having with the example at the link?

Comment: I might add that the example is also harder for a user to use and far more confusing. I still stand by the 2 dropdown boxes for best UI practice.